# Expression Tree Multiple Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I am building an advanced search feature using Linq to entities and an expression tree.  I have two entities, Entity A and Entity B where A is the parent and has a one to many relationship with B.

I have the expression tree for the fields in Entity A completed and the Linq query works as expected.  What I'm trying to add is a feature where I can query to return Entity A records where a field in Entity B contains some text.

I've found enough hints out there to be fairly sure I can do this, but I'm trying to make it all into one tree so I can cumulatively filter.  So I want to be able to say, more or less:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EntityA EA 
WHERE EA.FieldA = 'exampleinsql' 
AND 'test' in (SELECT EB.FieldB
               FROM EntityB EB 
               WHERE EntityB.EntityAForeignKey = EA.ID)
```

if that makes sense?

What I am doing currently is passing a list of filter objects and then combining a bunch of Expressions together using the below code snippits:

```
Expression expBody = ParseOperator(
        Expression.Property(pe, filtersList.FirstOrDefault().FieldName), 
        filtersList.FirstOrDefault().Operator, 
        Expression.Constant(filtersList.FirstOrDefault().GetTypedValue()));
expBody = Expression.AndAlso(expBody, newExp);
```

As I mention, this works great for columns on the main entity.  My understanding is that for EntityB I need to create a Lambda expression to add to this.  Am I on the right track?  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: So after doing additional research into this I realized I was re-inventing the wheel and was half way through recreating this: https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Going to try that out and see if I can get it to work the way i need.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to manipulate expressions at all.  Just use regular lambdas to write a query like this:

```
var query = from a in context.EntityA 
    where a.FieldA == "exampleinsql" &&
        context.EntityB.Where(b => b.EntityAForeignKey == a.ID)
        .Select(b => b.FieldB)
        .Contains("test")
    select a;
```

Of course, you could alternatively just do a `Join` for a query like this.

Comment: You'd need a select after `Where` to call `Contains<string>`.

Comment: The reason I went the expression tree route to begin with was I was trying to make it reusable across several different entities.  I didn't want to include multiple Wheres in the linq query to avoid making it entity specific.

Comment: @yanbu Just have all of the entities implement an interface with all of the needed information, and write the query against the interface.